# How to handle forgotten PIN for kids' banking app

Tags: mobile, security, password-recovery

How should a kids' banking app handle kids forgetting their PIN? This app is just for teaching purposes.

No email or account number confirmation flow would work.

I'm not allowed to share too much information here because of confidentiality.

Comment: Does the app 'just for teaching purpose', actually handle real money ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with children's apps, but what I have seen generally involves two levels of control: one for the child and another for the parent.

So I imagine that in the event (even if it is a hypothetical one) that the child forgets the password and is unable to do the more complex tasks required to restore the password, the adult can take over and handle the process.

However, from my experience with children's app, the parents are normally the ones that provide access to the app and the children don't normally deal with the administrative side of things. This should be the approach taken now for things like in-app purchases when children should not be making financial decisions, at least without the supervision or certain access allowed by the parents.

Comment: that's makes perfect sense. Thank you for helping me out here!

Answer (score 0):

It is a HUGE security risk to apply anything but the most stringent security measures for banking account access *no matter what* the age of the user is.

Use the exact same measures you would for an adult, otherwise you are creating a security risk.

Even if the app is for training, treat the security as if it was real, as this is a very important thing to teach children.